# Not reading the path in MATLAB on Mac

Tags: macos, matlab

I am using a Mac and in MATLAB when I use this code:

```
projectdir = '‎\Users\golnoush\ultrasound\papers'
dinfo = dir(fullfile(projectdir));
dinfo([dinfo.isdir]) = [];     %get rid of all directories including . and ..
nfiles = length(dinfo)
```

I get:

```
projectdir =
    '?\Users\golnoush\ultrasound\papers'
nfiles = 0
```

I could not find out why I get file numbers equal to zero while I have 17 PDFs in the `papers` directory. And what does "?" mean before the path? I am in the directory of `ultrasound` now. I think the problem comes back to something in using MATLAB on Mac that I do not know.

Edit: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilx7u.png) is the attached photo.

Comment: I am running this code without any problem on windows but on Mac I have this problem. is the problem from path?

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS, as on all other Unix-based systems, the path separator is the forward slash, not the backward slash. You need to write

```
projectdir = '‎/Users/golnoush/ultrasound/papers'
```

Also, `fullfile` serves to stitch together path components, you shouldn’t use it if you only have one argument to pass to it.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have changed based on what you said but I still have the same problem. I have edited my question and attached the photo of what I have.

Comment: @gxa: Do you maybe have an invisible character between the opening quote and the first slash? Or maybe the quote character itself is the problem?

Comment: @gxa: Also, see the underline by `clear all`? Look at those warnings, do as the editor tells you, you’ll learn lots of good MATLAB knowledge. :)

Comment: @gxa to ensure that your path `projectdir` is correctly use it as an input argument to the command `cd`. If matlab enters the directory you have one concern less.